# Is there a way to put PyDev's @UndefinedVariable in multiline statements?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I am using PyDev with Eclipse and I have some attributes that are only set during runtime. Normally I can fix PyDev's errors like this:

```
obj.runtime_attr  # @UndefinedVariable
```

However, since my statement is long and thus, with respect to PEP8, multiline, it looks like this:

```
some.long.statement.\
with.multiline(obj.runtime_attr).\
more()
```

Now I cannot add `@UndefinedVariable` because it breaks line continuation (PEP8 demands there are two spaces before a line-ending comment). However, I cannot put it in the end of the line (it just doesn't work):

```
some.long.statement.\
with.multiline(obj.runtime_attr).\
more()  # @UndefinedVariable
```

Is there any way this could work that I am overlooking? Is this just a missing feature where you cannot get it right?

Comment: AFAIK PEP8 *always* discourages using ```\``` for line-continuation. Group the lines with parentheses! `(some.long.statement.with.multiline(obj.runtime_attr).more())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, remember that [the most important rule of PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds) is:

> But most importantly: know when to be inconsistent -- sometimes the style guide just doesn't apply. When in doubt, use your best judgment. Look at other examples and decide what looks best.

And it specifically says to avoid a rule:

> When applying the rule would make the code less readable, even for someone who is used to reading code that follows the rules.

That being said, you're already violating the letter and the spirit of PEP 8 just by having these lines of code, unless you can't avoid it without making things worse. As [Maximum Line Length](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) says, using backslash continuations is the least preferred way to deal with long lines. On top of that, it specifically says to "Make sure to indent the continued line appropriately", which you aren't doing.

---

The obvious way to break this up is to use some intermediates variables. This isn't C++; there's no "copy constructor" cost to worry about. In a real-life example (unlike this toy example), there are probably good names that you can come up with that will be much more meaningful than the long expression they replace.

```
intermediate = some.long.statement
multiline = intermediate.with.multiline(obj.runtime_attr)
more = multiline.more()
```

---

If that isn't appropriate, as PEP 8 explicitly says, it's better to rely on parenthetical continuations than backslash continuations. Is that doable here? Sure:

```
some.long.statement.with.multiline(
    obj.runtime_attr).more()
```

Or, if worst comes to worst:

```
(some.long.statement.
 with.multiline(obj.runtime_attr).more())
```

This sometimes makes things less readable rather than more, in which case you shouldn't do it. But it's always an option. And if you have to go to extraordinary lengths to make backslash continuation work for you, it's probably going to be worse than even the worst excesses of over-parenthetizing.

---

At any rate, doing things either of these ways means you can put a comment on the end of each line, so your problem never comes up in the first place.

Comment: The code example comes from SQLAlchemy. There it is simply not the preferred way to split it into variables but build a query like this (this can be like 10 lines and finding a name for each is very wasteful). However, I will try the parenthesis. As with indentation: That was simply lost in the process of doing it here

Comment: @javex: You don't need to break _every_ attribute/method into a separate line, just break it into two or three pieces. I do this all the time with PyObjC, appscript, and other libraries that tend toward excessively-long lines, and it works just as well with sqlalchemy. Usually there are good conceptual places to put a break—a chain of attributes that go together better than they go with the adjacent lookups.